# Simplifying a boolean expression with 4 variables

Tags: boolean, expression, simplify

I can't figure this one out, I'm going insane looking through my textbook.

The expression is: (!w && !x && !y && z) || (w && !x && !y && z) || (x && z) || (x && y && !z)

Using distributive and compliment laws, I have narrowed it down to:
(!x && !y && z) || (x && z) || (x && y && !z)

But I can't narrow it any further!  The answer is supposed to be (x && y) || ( !y && z)  but I can't figure out what law would put me there.  My teacher told me to use distributive but wouldn't help me further.  That doesn't make any sense since there's nothing I can factor out and get rid of.  What law am I supposed to use next?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand `xz` to `x(y + !y)z` => `xyz + x!yz`.

Now you have `!x!yz + xyz + x!yz + xy!z`.

Then `!x!yz + x!yz` simplifies to `!yz`, and `xyz + xy!z` simplifies to `xy`,
giving the minimal expression.